# How can catch validation message?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have some test for field validation.
How I can assert response error message? 
this is my simple test

```
/** @test */
public function categoryRequiresName()
{



$response = $this->postGraphQL([
    'query' => '
        mutation CreateCategory($name: String!) {
            createCategory(name: $name) {
                name
            }
        }
    ',
    'variables' => [
        'name' => '',
    ],
]);

// how to assert Response message ?
// edited solution
$this->assertEquals("The name field is required.", $response->json("errors.0.extensions.validation.name.0"));
}
```

this is my rule at mutation field

```
name: String @rules(apply: ["required"])
```

this is error tree

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to validate, if you are getting correct response message? if yes check https://github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/unittest/blob/master/tests/Feature/CarouselFeatureTest.php

Comment: as you can see on screenshot i debugged response. it gives correct message but i don't know how assert it

Comment: If you want to assert the whole `$errors` array that will be difficult, if you want to assert the message, you can just compare the message, for `$errors` array, you may need to write a customize function to check whatever in that array and assert the return boolean value here.

Comment: ok thx bro... i need just test message which contains name array e.g "The name field is required"

Comment: Then use `assertSessionHas('message',  'your message to compare')`.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu thank u. i passed test with `$this->assertEquals("The name field is required.", $response->json("errors.0.extensions.validation.name.0"));`

Comment: `assertSessionHas` not working?

Comment: nope :(  .......